# Variance result differ in R language

Tags: statistics

I have dataset with 61 entries.
What i am trying to do is to calculate variance.

I am doing it with two ways but they differ

1st way is following

$var X = E(X^{2}) - (EX)^{2}$

so

```
> c = 0

> for( year in females$Salary )
+     c = c + (year^2)
> (c/length(females$Salary) - mean(females$Salary)^2
[1] 286682.3
```

but when i use build in function

```
> var(females$Salary)
[1] 291460.3
```

as u can see the output is different. Why is this happening? Shouldnt they be the same?

Answer (score 2):

The sample variance is traditionally computed as $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x})^2$. In the expanded form is $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2x_i \overline{x} + \overline{x}^2=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 - \frac{n}{n-1} \overline{x}^2$. This is called the Bessel correction, and it ensures that the sample variance is a consistent estimator of the underlying population variance, i.e. $E[S^2]=\sigma^2$. (Notably, $E[S] \neq \sigma$, but we use it to estimate $\sigma$ anyways.)

Intuitively the reason that the Bessel correction is required is that the $x_i$ tend to be a little bit closer to $\overline{x}$ than they are to the underlying mean, so dividing by $n-1$ instead of $n$ "counteracts" that. (Or a lot closer, if $n$ is small.) There is also an explanation in terms of the general concept of degrees of freedom.

If in fact the vector under consideration is the whole population and not a sample, then the Bessel correction is not necessary (and in fact is just wrong). But this is highly unusual in statistics.

Answer (score 1):

While V[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 is the population variance (when the values in the vector are the whole population, not just a sample), the var function calculates an estimator for the population variance (the sample variance)